# Unity + ARCore : no color picker for point cloud

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ubuntu-18.04, arcore

#### Issue:

I'm trying to draw the anchor points detected by ARCore with Unity to build an APK package for Android following a [tutorial](https://haptic.al/arcore-101-fa6f93d4c003) but I have no color picker as displayed in the tutorial at the point "*Change the color as you want, and the size of the point*" in front of variable "PointCloud color":

[image: pointcloud color]

So my points stay black.
How to fix this?

**Informations:**

I'm using Unity 2018.1.0b13 on Ubuntu 18.04 with the "ARCore SDK for Unity 1.7.0" (file: `arcore-unity-sdk-1.7.0.unitypackage`) coming from the link given on the official documentation for Unity+Android:
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android

Answer (score 0):

Select the Object from inspector "Add Component" --> point cloud visualizer, and there you will get these options such as color picker and size

[image]